# What's the '=>' operator in ASP.NET inside a Html method used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know the question is a little be tricky. I know what that operator does, but what I don't understand is, for instance, these lines of code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
</div>
```

The parameter of EditorFor or ValidationMessageFor, is it supposed to be a lambda or what? At first I thought, oh, it's a lambda expression (I was still confused by it, though), but then I saw this:

```
@foreach(var item in Model) {
 <tr>
      <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title);
      </td>
 </tr>
}
```

And then I said, I don't know, that doesn't look a lambda expression, the left side is supposed to be the parameter, and the right side what it returns (or the body), and then I said: "Uhm, alright, that ain't using the parameter,... so what the heck is that?"

I know it's a little bit of a dumb question, but I like to know how everything works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're still lambda methods, just ones that aren't using the parameters passed in to them.

Comment: Love the running commentary on your thought process, lol :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HtmlHelper basicly has this definition:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Foo<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var method = expression.Compile();

    //Pass the current model as parameter to your compiled expression:
    var value = method(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

    //Convert the result of your Expression to a String:
    return new MvcHtmlString(value.ToString());
}
```

What you pass in, is of type `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>`. So yes, it is a Lamda Expression

The parameter `model` only passes an object (your model) as parameter. `model.title` returns the title of that object.

The confusion, that comes from your foreach loop with `modelItem` is nothing other. You are just not using `modelItem`.

Answer (score 0):

It just isn't using the parameter from the lambda, that parameter could be named anything,  like   `thisIsATotallyUselessParameterBecauseImjustgonnauseItem => item.Title`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a regular lambda expression. I like to read a lambda as "for some variable x, do something." Usually the "do something" means do something *with x*, but technically you are allowed to disregard x. For example: "for some variable x, do something with items."